# On the definition of subsheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

[image]

Can someone explain the definition of a subsheaf here, I am somewhat confused about the restriction map, I can't understand why $\rho_{\mathscr{K},U,V}(\mathscr{K}(U)) \subseteq \mathscr{K}(V)$ for the restriction map?

Also the last part seems a little strange, the quotient sheaf $\mathscr{F}/ \mathscr{K}$ is defined to be the **sheaf** associated to the **presheaf** $U \mapsto \mathscr{F}(U) / \mathscr{K}(U)$. What is meant here, is it a sheaf or presheaf?

Comment: @EricWofsey I missed adding the actual function. Edited the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is not true that $\rho_{\mathscr{F},U,V}(\mathscr{K}(U)) \subseteq \mathscr{K}(V)$, then you just don't have a subsheaf.  In other words, a subsheaf is given by a family of subgroups $\mathscr{K}(U)\subseteq\mathscr{F}(U)$ *such that* $\rho_{\mathscr{F},U,V}(\mathscr{K}(U)) \subseteq \mathscr{K}(V)$ is always true, and then you make this family of subgroups into a presheaf by restricting the restriction maps from $\mathscr{F}$.  (To have a subsheaf, this presheaf must then additionally actually be a sheaf.)

For the quotient sheaf, there is a presheaf $Q$ defined by $Q(U)=\mathscr{F}(U)/\mathscr{K}(U)$.  This presheaf may or may not be a sheaf.  The quotient sheaf $\mathscr{F}/\mathscr{K}$ is then defined as the sheafification of this presheaf $Q$.

Comment: Great clarification. Its much clearer now. 

Can I just ask, do you consider the definition entirely correctly phrased? I dont see where the condition $\rho_{\mathscr{F},U,V}(\mathscr{K}(U)) \subseteq \mathscr{K}(V)$ appears in the definition. From what I see, he just says that we restrict $\rho$ to the subgroup.

Comment: The definition starts by saying that $\mathscr{K}$ is a sheaf.  If $\rho_{\mathscr{F},U,V}(\mathscr{K}(U)) \subseteq \mathscr{K}(V)$ was not true then it could not have well-defined restriction maps so it would not be a sheaf.

Comment: This is analogous to defining a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ to be a group whose underlying set is a subset of $G$ and whose operation is given by restricting the operation of $G$.  This definition does not explicitly say that $H$ is closed under the operation, but it must be, since otherwise $H$ would not be a group to begin with.

Comment: Sorry but I dont follow the last part, can you explain it in more detail. Sure we have a sheaf, but if the inclusion criteria is not true, why would the restriction maps not be well defined?

Comment: The restriction map $\rho_{\mathscr{K},U,V}$ must be a map $\mathscr{K}(U)\to\mathscr{K}(V)$.  So, the restriction of $\rho_{\mathscr{F},U,V}$ to $\mathscr{K}(U)$ must have image contained in $\mathscr{K}(V)$.

Comment: OK I see what you are saying, I mixed up some thing. Thanks for the answer.